# images distorted on iphone

Tags: css, iphone

Working on a site and tested it on android but finding out there's an issue with image distortion on iPhone: https://www.prestigemountainchalets.com/wellness

This is how the image is set on the template

```
<img alt="" class="img-fluid col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-1" src="/media/ckeditor/2019/10/29/download_11.jpeg">
```

I'm using bootstrap 4 so this is the css targeting this image

```
.mb-1, .my-1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-md-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.col-sm-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.col-12 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I've not used any custom css on this image so it uses only the Bootstrap styling listed.

This is how it looks on android

[image]

vs how it looks on iPhone

[image]

Done some research and the closest and most likely solution seems to be that flex isn't well supported on iPhone but that's not what I see from canIuse: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

They're using the latest version of chrome 78 so if maybe not, the option seems to hinge more on using bootstrap 3. What do you think?

Comment: The image in the carousel hav an inline height element(probably added via js) you have to remove this. don't use col- class for image it is for container. And remeber if an img is flexbox child it have by dafault align-items: stretch

Comment: @Sfili_81 this affects the images below the caurosel not the caurosel.

Comment: In your link i'll see the problem only in the carousel

Comment: you haven't added an align-items property to your `.row.text-center` which contains those images. try adding one like, `.row.text-center { align-items: center;  }` and also make sure to auto-prefix your code so it's compatible with all browsers